# How to override where images are stored by CarrierWave? def store_dir doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm moving from attachment_fu to carrierwave, since attachment_fu is broken with Rails 3, and would like to be able to use the attachment_fu image files that I already have, instead of carrierwave making new ones and moving them somewhere else.

My images are partitioned by id, so if the user id is `61` and they upload a file called `"foo.png"`, then their old attachment_fu image would be at `"public/images/users/0000/0061/foo.png"`

In my users model, I mount the carrierwave image uploader with:

```
attr_accessible :user_avatar
mount_uploader :user_avatar, UserAvatarUploader
```

In my `UserAvatarUploader`, I have this:

```
def store_dir
  File.join Rails.root, "public/images/users", ("%08d" % model.id).scan(/\d{4}/).join("/")
end
```

so when I set `:user_avatar`, I should get `"public/images/users/0000/0061/foo.png"`

but when I try to set the `:user_avatar` in the `User` model to the old image

```
user.user_avatar = "#{Rails.root}/public/images/users/0000/0061/foo.png"
```

it comes back as something like `"/uploads/tmp/20110916-1244-15398-7724/foo.png"`

It seems that `store_dir` is not being overwritten properly. What do I need to do to make this work right?

Comment: Can you show (a) the model code mounting the uploader, and (b) where you set the old image (and what exactly you mean by that)?

Comment: Updated it with model code. Sorry if it wasn't clear on the old image. The old image was created by attachment_fu. I want carrierwave to use that image and the same path to it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering if it only uses `store_dir` when you actually upload, not if you set it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave default base location is the public folder

try to change it by using

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```